# Как определять свойства класса в питон?

Tags: python-3.x, ооп

Надеюсь не начнется холивар, ибо в питоне я только начинаю разбираться. Знаю ООП в c++, а от ООП в питоне глазам больно, но если есть какой-то стандарт(вроде тех же стандартов написания имен переменных верблюдом), скажите.

---

Т.е. я вижу, что могу сделать так:

```
class A:
    a = ''
```

---

Либо так:

---

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value=''):
        a = value
```

Либо вместе. Могу вообще не объявлять, а использовать эту переменную где нибудь в коде, но о таком наверное даже упоминать не надо...
Если есть стандарт, то как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй вариант правильный.
То есть так:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value=''):
        a = value
```

Несколько основных правил оформления кода на python: https://netology-university.bitbucket.io/codestyle/python/

А вообще по моему мнению задавать такие вопросы абсолютно нормально, холи вар из-за такого не начинают)
Все когда-то осваивали новые языки.